# Group by gives different results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this:

```
 SELECT   ([Document No_]) 
 FROM [Verploegen POC$Sales Line]
 --WHERE [Shipment Date] = '2014-05-08' 
 GROUP BY [Document No_]
 --[Shipment Date]
 --[Document No_], 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and gives me 272160 results back.

But If I do this:

```
  SELECT   ([Document No_]), [Shipment Date] 
FROM [Verploegen POC$Sales Line]
--WHERE [Shipment Date] = '2014-05-08' 
GROUP BY [Document No_], [Shipment Date]
--[Shipment Date]
--[Document No_], 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

it returns: 267661.

How can that be?

Thank you

If I do this:

```
SELECT   ([Document No_]), [Shipment Date] 
FROM [Verploegen POC$Sales Line]
WHERE [Shipment Date] = '2012-01-01'
```

I get 36 results back. But there are doubles, like this:

```
V004180 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V004182 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
V066594 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

SO I try to delte the doubles with having by. But how to return in this case just tree results(that are the unique values) with header: document No_ and shipment date?

Thank you

If I do this:

```
SELECT (  [Document No_]), [Shipment Date], COUNT(*) as count
FROM [Verploegen POC$Sales Line] 
WHERE [Shipment Date] = '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY [Document No_], [Shipment Date]


SELECT (  [Document No_]), COUNT(*) as count
FROM [Verploegen POC$Sales Line] 
WHERE [Shipment Date] = '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY [Document No_]
```

It will return exactly the same results

Comment: erm... because they are different queries?!

Comment: But I just add as header shipment date. So I want to show the document No_ and shipment date.

Comment: well we have no idea what your data looks like, but if you have different grouping with extra columns you are likely to see a different number of results.

Comment: @NielsKing  you have changed the group by   columns this mean that you are performing the count respect to a  new rules of counting

Comment: Those ~4.5K rows with same `Document No` have different `Shipment Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Right!

You are executing two different query.

The first group by only for Document_No, the second group by for two fields, Document_No and Shipment Date

An example.

Suppose you have this datas:

```
Document No | Shipment Date
    1       |    2015-01-01
    2       |    2015-01-01
    1       |    2016-01-01
```

The first query returns 2 ROWS (group by Document No, so the first and the third rows collpased and the second row)

The second query returns 3 ROWS (group by Docvument No and Shipment Date are three different combinations).

An interesting question is... How in your table you have more rows for the same Document No? And why you have different Shipment Date for the same Document No?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different queries, so two different result sets should not be a surprise. In a really simple example:

Raw Data:

```
Document No |  Shipment Date
-----------------------------
    1       |  2016-07-22
    1       |  2016-07-23
    2       |  2016-07-22
```

If you do a count grouping just by `Document No`, you would get:

```
SELECT  [Document No], COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM    T
GROUP BY [Document No];

Document No |  Count
-----------------------------
    1       |  2
    2       |  1
```

So after applying `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` you would only be left with the record where `Document No` is 1.

If you add Shipment Date to the query:

```
SELECT  [Document No], [Shipment Date], COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM    T
GROUP BY [Document No], [Shipment Date];

Document No |  Shipment Date | Count
--------------------------------------
    1       |  2016-07-22    |   1
    1       |  2016-07-23    |   1
    2       |  2016-07-22    |   1
```

So after you apply the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` clause you are left with no rows. This is why your second query has less rows than the first.

As an aside, I would strongly suggest you stop creating object names with spaces and symbols in. It is a little subjective, in my opinion Pascal case is fine, I don't see that `DocumentNo` is any less legible than `[Document No_]`, and significantly easier to write. At the very worst (I don't like it but I know it is popular) you should use an underscore rather than a space to separate words, so you end up with `Document_No`. If of course you have just inherited this system, and it is too late to make changes, then you should at least take the original creator of these tables off your Christmas Card list!

Comment: See my post ok, yes

Comment: I have seen the edit, but I am still not sure what you are asking. I have explained, with examples why you get different results when you have different group by columns. What exactly are you trying to do, and what problem are you having?

Comment: So as header: document no_ and shipment date. and then show only the unique Document No_